# How to open online reference from IPython?

Tags: numpy, ipython

Is there a way to have IPython open a browser pointed at the appropriate online reference?

Especially for `numpy`,`scipy`, `matplotlib`?

For example, the doc for [numpy.linalg.cholesky](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.cholesky.html) is pretty hard to read in a terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a direct way to make IPython or any shell to open up documentation online, because the primary job of shells is to let you interact with the things they are shells to.

We could however write a script to open a new tab on a browser with the documentation. Like so:

```
import webbrowser

docsList = {
    "numpy" : lambda x: "https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/" + x + ".html",
    "scipy" : lambda x: "https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/" + x + ".html",
    "matplotlib" : lambda x: "https://matplotlib.org/api/" + x.split('.')[1] + "_api.html",
    "default" : lambda x: "https://www.google.com/search?q=documentation+" + x
    }

def online(method_name):
    """
    Opens up the documentation for method_name on the default browser.
    If the package doesn't match any entry in the dictionary, falls back to
    Google.

    Usage
    -------
    >>> lookUp.online("numpy.linalg.cholesky")
    >>> lookUp.online("matplotlib.contour")
    """
    try:
        url = make_url(method_name)
    except AttributeError:
        print("Enter the method name as a string and try again")
        return

    webbrowser.open(url, new = 2)
    return


def make_url(method_name):
    package_name = method_name.split('.')[0]
    try:
        return docsList[package_name](method_name)
    except KeyError:
        return docsList["default"](method_name)
```

You could save the above as "lookUp.py" at a location that Python can find it in, and then import it whenever you need to use it.

**Caveats:**

This method takes strings as input, so if you call it on a function it'll throw an error.

```
>>> lookUp.online("numpy.linalg.cholesky")
```

Will work.

```
>>> lookUp.online(numpy.linalg.cholesky)
```

Will ask you to give it as a string.
So use autocomplete to get to the function and then wrap it in quotes to get it to work.